# Automatic array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

How about, make this example, where we put an initial number and final number.
Example We insert the Initial and Final Number:

```
Initial Number = 1 Final Number = 4

    Result = 1 2 3 4
```

The result is thrown when we press the SEND button.

What I want is that I throw my result without having to press the SEND button.
That the FOR cycle is performed and I throw the result without pressing the button.
That the result is automatic.

CODE:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="inivalue" id="inivalue" placeholder="initial value"/>
  <input type="text" name="finvalue" id="finvalue" placeholder="final value"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" vale="submit" />
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$num = (int)$_POST['inivalue'];
$numfin = (int)$_POST['finvalue'];
for($num=$num; $num <= $numfin; $num++)
{
echo $num;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want this to be done automatically I would recommend javascript. Using PHP would be making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: so you want to do `oncomplete` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Get your input elements using getElementById()
const initialValue = document.getElementById("inivalue");
const finalValue = document.getElementById("finvalue");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
let initialVal = "";
let finalVal = "";

// Every time you change the value in your <input> element
// save that value into the initialVal, finalVal variables.

initialValue.addEventListener("change", function(){
    initialVal = this.value;
    autoArray(initialVal,finalVal);
});

finalValue.addEventListener("change", function(){
    finalVal= this.value;
    autoArray(initialVal,finalVal);
});

// Loop using initialVal and finalVal
function autoArray(ini,fin){
  numArray = [];
  if (ini!= "" && fin != "") {
    for(i = ini; i <= fin; i++){
      numArray.push(i);
    }
  }
  // Change the value of the result <input> element
  result.value = numArray;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inivalue" id="inivalue" placeholder="initial value"/>
  <input type="text" name="finvalue" id="finvalue" placeholder="final value"/>
  <input type="text" id="result"/>
```

Comment: You might want to add another condition to check if both the inputs are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is using the [onChange event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).

set it in your final number field:

```
<input onchange = "rangefinder()" type="text" name="finvalue" id="finvalue" placeholder="final value"/>
```

then in your javascript function `rangefinder()`:

```
function rangefinder(){
    //get the value of both the invalue and finalvalue fields
    //make sure they're both integers - just return if they're not.
    //use a for loop to make a string of numbers from invalue to finalvalue
    //insert this string where ever you want it.
}
```

I'll leave the actual JS up to you.

Comment: array() has special meaning in JS. You might want to change the name of your function.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed!

Comment: For the js lines have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069315/create-array-of-all-integers-between-two-numbers-inclusive-in-javascript-jquer