# Generate reversed range with supplied bounds

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, range

This question is similar to an existing one: [Create array of all integers between two numbers, inclusive, in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069315/create-array-of-all-integers-between-two-numbers-inclusive-in-javascript-jquer)

However, instead of simply generating a range between two bounds `min` and `max`, I'd like to create a range between to numbers `start` and `end` with a specified `limit`.

#### Example:

`start` *19*
`end` *30*
`limit` *60*

*Result:* `[19, 20, 21, 22, ..., 28, 29, 30]`

Whereas
`start` *30*   <--\
`end` *19*       <--/
`limit` *60*

*Result:* `[30, 31, 32, ..., 58, 59, 60, 1, 2, 3, ..., 17, 18, 19]`

Note that: No element of the array can ever be greater than `limit`.

I'm guessing I'd also have to define a lower limit (1 in this case to exclude zero fro the array).

How can I achieve this in plain ES6?

Comment: what is the result for `start : 10 , end : 20 ,limit : 15` values ?

Comment: @EhsanNazeri That will be `[10, 11, ..., 14, 15]` - `limit` should have the highest precedence in that case (no number can ever be greater than `limit`)

Comment: So just `if (start > end) return [...range(start, limit), ...range(0, end)] else return range(start, end)`?

Comment: @Bergi Haha, I love how people can turn problems that seems difficult at first into a very simple one! Yeah, that's exactly it

Comment: @Bergi it has a problem. change it to this `if (start > end) return [...range(start, limit), ...range(0, end)] else return range(start, Math.min([end,limit])`

Comment: Either of you feel free to take the credit and provide an answer if you like

Comment: @EhsanNazeri I didn't think end (or start) could be larger than limit, but yeah that's a nice edge case requiring treatment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation of this, maybe not the best one, but it works.

It determines the direction of the range using `Math.sign(end-start)`, and has `min` and `max` parameters:

```js
const range = ({
  start,
  end,
  min = -Infinity,
  max = Infinity
}) => {
  if(Math.floor(start) !== start || Math.floor(end) !== end) throw new Error('Invalid numbers')
  const 
    sign = Math.sign(end - start),
    arr = [],
    push = n => {
      if (min <= n && n <= max) arr.push(n)
    }
  for (let n = start; n !== end; n += sign)
    push(n)
  push(end)
  return arr
}

console.log(range({start: 30, end: 19, max: 60}))
```