# Creating a range function that pushes all the numbers to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, range, push

I am creating a function that adds the numbers within the parameters start to end to an array. I have kind of accomplished that but the function adds a few numbers beyond the end number. I have probably overcomplicated things here...

```
function range(start, end){

  let numbersArray = [];
 
  let counter = 0;
  
  while(counter < end){
    counter++
    
    if (counter < end){
    numbersArray.push(start++)}
 
    };
  return numbersArray
};

console.log(range(4, 11));
//[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case at `counter` the beginning must be equal `start`. Because of that there is no need in variable `counter`, can use `start`:

```js
function range(start , end){
  let numbersArray = [];
  while(start <= end){ 
    numbersArray.push( start );
    start += 1;
  };

  return numbersArray
};
```

But `while` can lead to eternal loop, so better use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33457557/16236820)

Comment: Thx! Thats what I was stuck with... I added an equal sign after while(start <= end) so it includes the end as well.

Comment: Welcome @tyskas at SO! Do not forget to upvote and accept answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/bagnk3z4/2/

```
function range(start, end) {
    let array = [];
    while (start <= end) {
        array.push(start++);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Heyy... thx for the input. The jsfiddle link stuff I havent learned yet but I am sure it works as well. Taking my baby steps :)