# Generate Array of Values between Min and Max

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Looking to create a function in (vanilla) JavaScript that generates an array with *n* values between a *min* and *max* value, where *n* is a specified number of steps. The first value should be the *min*, the last should be the *max*.

i.e.

```
function returnAllSteps(min,max,totalSteps) {
  var steps = new Array(totalSteps);
  for (i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
    steps[i] = // HELP: return number value between min and max?
  }
  console.log(steps);
}
returnAllSteps(0,10,30); // min = 0, max = 10, totalSteps = 30 (give me an array with 30 steps between 0 and 10)
```

I would also like to be able to return a single step value within the range. Does this have to happen in a different function?

i.e.

```
function returnStep(min,max,totalSteps,stepNumberToReturn) {
  // HELP: do I even need another function to do this?
}
returnStep(0,10,30,20); // min = 0, max = 10, totalSteps = 30, stepNumberToReturn = 20
// Return the value at array[20 - 1]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create array of all integers between two numbers, inclusive, in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069315/create-array-of-all-integers-between-two-numbers-inclusive-in-javascript-jquer)

Comment: @HereticMonkey no.  different requirements.

Comment: @Tibrogargan That's not how we counter duplicate proposals on Stack Overflow. See the last paragraph of https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: See also [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate a range within the supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3895478/215552), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3895521/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey oddly enough, that answer exhibits exactly why this question is not a duplicate, since JavaScript floating point math behavior will make it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one function is needed to generate and return an array with all steps:

```js
function returnAllSteps(min, max, totalSteps) {
  let steps = new Array(totalSteps);
  let distance = max - min;
  for (i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
    steps[i] = min + distance * (i / (totalSteps - 1));
  }
  return steps;
}

let mySteps = returnAllSteps(0, 10, 30); // min = 0, max = 10, totalSteps = 30 (give me an array with 30 steps between 0 and 10)
console.log(mySteps);
```

Then just get the step you need from `mySteps` directly. For example: `mySteps[20]`

Comment: Maybe `let step = (max - min) / (totalSteps - 1)` and `steps[i] = min + step * i`

Comment: Also maybe explain why the for loop should not be `for (i = min; i <= max; i += step)`